# How to stop jetty if run by double clicking?

Tags: java, server, jetty, port

I installed the jetty java server on Windows. I went to the installation directory and double-clicked on the start.jar file. Now a server is constantly listening at port 8080. I need to stop this server.

I checked both online and the documentation and the closest I've come to the solution is this:

```sh
$ {jetty home}/ java -jar start.jar STOP.KEY=[PASSWORD] STOP.PORT=[PORT] --stop
```

I have tried this many times but it doesn't work. Also tried without the `STOP.PORT` directive and without the `STOP.PASS` directive with no success. Apparently, I need the `STOP.KEY` which was used to start the server. But, as I double-clicked the .jar file to run it, I have no idea of what I have actually done. I've been looking for several hours for some sort of default password, or a service to kill, anything that allows me to free the port 8080 but I haven't found any solutions.

There is a question about how to stop it from Eclipse but didn't work for me.

Does anyone know how to kill jetty if it started double-clicking the start.jar file?

Comment: Task Manager?...

Comment: No, it's not there either. I have checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the solution. But it´s a workaround if you need to stop the process somehow:

Found in this question by [@brad-wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1554/brad-wilson) [how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

1. First, find the process running on the port:

```bsh
PS: Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort <PORT>).OwningProcess
```

2. Then kill it like this:

```bsh
PS: Stop-Process -Name <PROCESS_NAME>
```

This should have freed the port.